# Thread-safe очередь, и все-все-все

Tags: очередь, c, многопоточность, c++

Опять у меня идиотский вопрос (простите, но впадаю в старческий маразм, "бабушка ничего не помнит").

Дано: поток данных поступает в очередь (com-порт). Другой поток разгребает эту очередь, складывает разобраные данные в базу. Всё в рамках одного приложения.

Вопрос: что юзать в качестве очереди на C (возможно, C++)

Comment: компорт - штука нешустрая, достаточно будет `std::vecor< char >`

Comment: Меня интересуют в первую очередь всякие случаи, когда в очереди 0 элементов, и один поток что-то туда добавляет, а второй пытается забрать. Понятно, что второй поток сначала будет смотреть size(), но нет ли тут каких неочевидностей? Правда, давно очень не имел дело.

Comment: Да, и речь не о char, первый поток перед записью в очередь формирует отдельную структуру по полученному. Протокол битовый.

Comment: >и один поток что-то туда добавляет, а второй пытается забрать.

Значит вопрос неправильно поставлен

>Да, и речь не о char, первый поток перед записью в очередь формирует отдельную структуру по полученному. Протокол битовый.

если Вы пишете что-то для **конкретного** устройства, по которому известен минимальный пакет данных, который посылается в линию, то и выбирайте его вместо `char`. Если Вам ничего о протоколе неизвестно, то `char` - само то. В этой очереди могут оставаться **незавершенные** пакеты, в случае, если Вы не знаете, на что устройство способно.

Comment: Протокол передачи это проблема первого потока. Какие данные он принимает с линии, и как обращается с ними - это в рамках задачи "чёрный ящик". До того момента, как он не начнёт складывать в очередь. Вопрос в том, как избежать конфликта между потоками.

Comment: @klopp: а чем вам не угодил std::mutex?

Comment: @VladD, просто я с сями и плюсами давно реальной практики не имел. Направление понял, сенкс :)

Answer (score 3):

Видимо что-то в таком духе (увидел знакомую тему и не удержался).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct qitem {
  struct qitem *next;
  int len;
  char data[1];  // реально здесь будет len+1 байт данных
};

struct queue {
  struct qitem *head, *tail;  // head == tail == 0  очередь пуста
  pthread_mutex_t lock;       // мьютекс для всех манипуляций с очередью
  pthread_cond_t cond;        // этот cond "сигналим" когда очередь стала НЕ ПУСТОЙ
  pthread_t th;               // tid обработчика
};

void
inqueue (const char *str, int len, struct queue *q)
{
  struct qitem *p = (typeof(p))malloc(sizeof(*p) + len);
  strcpy(p->data, str);
  p->len = len;
  p->next = 0;
  pthread_mutex_lock(&q->lock);
  if (q->tail)
    q->tail->next = p;
  else {
    q->head = p;
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&q->cond);  // теперь очередь не пуста, сигнализируем
  }
  q->tail = p;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&q->lock);
}

void
processit (struct qitem *p)
{
  int t = atoi(p->data);
  if (t > 0) {
    printf ("Sleep %d\n", t);
    sleep(t);
  }
}

// обработчик очереди в отдельном потоке
void *
consumer (void *arg)
{
  struct queue *q = (typeof(q))arg;

  for (;;) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&q->lock);
    if (!q->head) { // очередь пуста, делать нечего, ждем...
      pthread_cond_wait(&q->cond, &q->lock);
      //pthread_mutex_unlock(&q->lock);  // это для нескольких обработчиков очереди
      //continue;                        // в нашем случае не нужно
      // для нескольких "concurrent" обработчиков нужна последовательность 
      // lock/check/wait/unlock/continue/lock/check...
    }
    struct qitem *p = q->head;
    q->head = q->head->next;
    q->nitems--;
    if (!q->head)
      q->tail = q->head;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&q->lock);

    printf ("consume: %s", p->data);
    if (strcmp(p->data, "STOP") == 0)
      break;
    processit(p);
    free(p);
  }
  return 0;
}

// сделаем пустую очередь и запустим ее обработчик в новом потоке
struct queue *
run_consumer()
{
  struct queue *q = (typeof(q))malloc(sizeof(*q));
  q->head = q->tail = 0;
  q->nitems = 0;
  pthread_mutex_init(&q->lock, 0);
  pthread_cond_init(&q->cond, 0);
  pthread_create(&q->th, 0, consumer, (void *)q);

  return q;
}

int
main ()
{
  void *res = 0;

  char *in = NULL;
  size_t sz;
  int l;

  struct queue *q = run_consumer();
  while ((l = getline(&in, &sz, stdin)) > 0) {
    inqueue(in, l, q);
    in = NULL;
  }

  inqueue("STOP", 5, q);
  if (pthread_join(q->th,  &res))
    perror("join");

  return (long)res;
}
```

Для тестирования просто читаем строки с клавиатуры, и ставим их в очередь. Обрааботчик их печатает. Если в начале строки число, то обработчик делает sleep, позволяя написать в очередь несколько строк.

Comment: О, producer-consumer на pthreads с правильными condition variable'ами. А давайте сделаем [исследование](http://hashcode.ru/research/) по имплементации таких штук на разных платформах? С меня вариант на C#.

Comment: > С меня вариант на C#.

Ваш вариант будет заключаться в использовании штатного класса ConcurrentQueue<T>. Там достаточно документацию открыть.

Comment: @VladD, давайте, но инициатива, как известно, наказуема... Так что теория за Вами.

Начинайте и сразу возьмите этот вариант (C linux pthreads), как простейший случай (1 х 1), а на днях я набросаю вариант (N x M) (собственно там самое сложное, это придумать прозрачную схему тестовой демонстрации) и сделаю обновление.

Интересно, кроме как на Java кто-нибудь приведет рабочие примеры?

Comment: Да что ж это за олимпиада велосипедистов?..

Comment: @Flammable, а что Вас это так задело?

Comment: @avp, вы тоже считаете более разумным написать такую простыню вместо использования boost::lockfree::queue?

Comment: @Flammable, начнем с того, что я не люблю кресты, а от вывода простыни при любой ошибке с бустом и скорости его компиляции - просто тошнит.

ТС спросил, как это делается на Си, я показал для Linux pthreads.

Как работает вариант (они говорят lock-free, а это просто настораживает) буста - не знаю. Попробуйте, поисследуйте с разных сторон и расскажите.

О самописном. В принципе, часто быстрее и безопасней написать свой конкретный вариант, чем хорошо изучить чужой обобщенный продукт. Если же тема сложная или есть общедоступный хорошо работающий чужой софт, то конечно, разумного изучить его.

Comment: Насчет быстрее и безопаснее - согласен. А в целом: чем меньше у инструмента "степеней свободы", тем меньше он таит подводных камней. Усложнять инструменты следует **пропорционально** усложнению самой задачи, это просто грамотное проектирование.

Comment: @avp: Сишную часть вроде адаптировал. Немного обобщил, старался не менять дух реализации. Гляньте, нет ли каких-то ошибок, а? (Компилятора под рукой нету сейчас, сорри.) http://hashcode.ru/research/221526/

Comment: @Flammable: добавите пример для C++ с lockfree::queue? http://hashcode.ru/research/221526/

Answer (score 1):

Я бы использовал просто `queue<char>`. Поскольку у вас доступ к очереди из нескольких потоков, вам нужно синхронизировать обращения к очереди.

Для синхронизации подошёл бы `std::mutex`, если он доступен на вашем компиляторе. В любом случае, *какая-то* синхронизация вам всё равно нужна, т.к. в её отсутствие у разных потоков может быть разное представление о содержимом памяти (например потому, что в многопроцессорной системе каждый процессор сбрасывает кэш независимо).

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [boost::lockfree::queue](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/queue.html)

Comment: неразумно, на мой взгляд )

Comment: @mega, куда разумнее писать свой кривой велосипед, так?

Comment: @Flammable, это просто не задача для `lock-free`. В данном случае требуется хранить набор байт и забирать/добавлять в эту очередь **заведомо неизвестное** их число. Наипростейший синхронизатор, типа мьютекса, обеспечит эксклюзивный доступ к такой очереди.  
 --  
А Вы предлагаете забивать гвозди микроскопом.

Comment: Вместо того, чтобы просто поюзать готовую очередь из почти что стандартной библиотеки, вы предлагаете написать обертку стандартной очереди с самописной синхронизацией по мьютексу. Ну, может где-то такое и считается разумнее.

Comment: Я работаю в `windows`, поэтому здесь я бы предложил стандартный путь:
`std::vector< char >` + `критическая секция`, без каких-либо оберток и уж точно без `lock-free` и буста. Простой задаче - простые инструменты!

Comment: В нормальном случае буст подключен по дефолту и его просто используют по назначению.

Comment: >и его просто используют по назначению

и это явно не тот случай :)